Add a subreport at the end without rendering Header and Footer
I'm not a novice in reporting ... rather an 'experienced user' but seems that this problem is pushing me to lessons from A ...
So, I have a report developed (not too complicated some tables, few text fields etc) that is having a Footer and Header carefully designed but not as image (company logo is image but lot of phones, and descriptions around it ... not saying that is important just describing) ...
So, on that report I need to add a page that would be some kind of Instructions page. It would go at the end and if shown or not will depend on certain parameter (pulled in separate dataset just to be sure)
When I try the subreport approach it does not print header/footer on last page but subreport (that would usually take some less than one page letter size) is divided and starts on last page minus one where it keeps the header footer.
I have tried using rectangles (around subreport) with page breaks. Then tried moving all the controls from the additional report to a rectangle (instead of a subreport), then forcing a page break before it (either rectangle or subreport) and all the stuff in between but failing to find a proper setting.
Of course, I know how to use 'Do not print on Last Page' setting

Eventually, I will try to change to a shell report that will use both (main and additional one) as subreprots but since the main one has to have header and footer and multiple pages I (from my previous experience) doubt that it will work.
Any suggestion that you know worked in some of your use cases.
Yes, I think the main problem is that even though I do not print h/f on last page rendering does reserve place for them (and that would be the reason it divides additional page) ...
I have set 'Consume white space' on report side even though I do not think it influence h/f space
Thank you
